# Concerning the coefficient $[q^n]\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(aq)^n}{(1-bq^n)^2}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, q-series

**I posted this on MSE, and not even @ParamanandSingh could answer, so I thought I should post it here**

Background:

While trying to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3782985/583016), I came up with a question of my own.

Let $|a|,|b|,|q|<1$ and
$$A(a,b;q)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(aq)^n}{1-bq^n}.$$
One can show that $$A(a,b;q)=\sum_{n\ge1}\phi_n(a,b)q^n,$$
where $$\phi_n(a,b)=\sum_{d|n}a^db^{n/d-1}.$$
Preforming the index shift $j=n/d$, we can write
$$\phi_n(a,b)=\sum_{j|n}a^{n/j}b^{j-1}=\frac{a}{b}\phi_n(b,a).$$
Thus $$A(a,b;q)=\frac{a}{b}A(b,a;q).\tag1$$
Then let $$B(a,b;q)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(aq)^n}{(1-bq^n)^2},$$
and we can see that
$$B(a,b;q)=\frac{\partial}{\partial b}A(a/q,b;q).$$
Then let $\sigma_n(a,b)=[q^n]B(a,b;q)$.

> Do these coefficients satisfy a similar symmetry under $(a,b)\mapsto (b,a)$ that $\phi_n$ does? In other words, is there a 'nice' relationship between $B(a,b;q)$ and $B(b,a;q)$?

My attempts are below.

I tried setting $M(a,b;q)=A(a/q,b;q)$, and I noticed that
$$\begin{align}
M(a,b;q)&=\frac{a}{bq}A(b,a/q;q)\\
&=a\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(bq)^{n-1}}{1-aq^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{a}{1-a}+a\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(bq)^{n}}{1-aq^{n}}\\
&=\frac{a}{1-a}+bA(a,b;q).
\end{align}$$
Thus
$$\begin{align}
B(a,b;q)&=\partial_b bA(a,b;q)\\
&=A(a,b;q)+b\partial_b A(a,b;q)\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}q^n\phi_n(a,b)+\sum_{n\ge1}q^nb\partial_b \phi_n(a,b)\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}q^n\left\{\sum_{d|n}a^db^{n/d-1}+b\sum_{d|n}\left(\tfrac{n}{d}-1\right)a^db^{n/d-2}\right\}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}q^n\sum_{d|n}\tfrac{n}{d}a^db^{n/d-1}.
\end{align}$$
Thus $$\sigma_n(a,b)=\sum_{d|n}\tfrac{n}{d}a^db^{n/d-1},$$
which we can write as $$\sigma_n(a,b)=\frac{a}{b}\sum_{d|n}db^da^{n/d-1},$$
which looks a lot like $\frac{a}{b}\sigma_n(b,a)$, but [this is not so](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/flabzxuhab).

> At this point I am at a loss for a formula that relates $\sigma_n(a,b)$ and $\sigma_n(b,a)$, so could I have some help? Thanks!

---

Update: a potentially fruitful side note.

We may notice that
$$\begin{align}
A(a,b;q)-B(a,b;q)&=\sum_{n\ge1}(aq)^n\left(\frac{1}{1-bq^n}-\frac{1}{(1-bq^n)^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}(aq)^n\frac{1-bq^n-1}{(1-bq^n)^2}\\
&=-b\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(aq^2)^n}{(1-bq^n)^2}\\
&=-bB(aq,b;q).
\end{align}$$
Whether or not this can be used is unclear to me.

Comment: I would be surprised if there is one such relation between $B(a,b;q)$ and $B(b,a;q)$.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan Why is that? I was thinking there would be because the symmetry of $A$ under $(a,b)\mapsto(b,a)$ is so simple and $A$ is intimately connected to $B$.